[cryptography] tag
Do we really need a tag cryptography? Seems redundant as most (all?) questions should be on that topic anyway.

I've added this to the blacklist, no need for the tag to exist on this site.

Could you add crypto as well? I already removed it once.

@PaŭloEbermann Done.

No.  E.g. the IT security site doesn't have a [security] tag either.
